# Slope of constant pressure line on $T$-$S$ plot

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, entropy

Is slope of constant pressure line is same or di in liquid region and super heated region for pure substance on $T$-$S$ diagram?

Answer (score 0):

$$U=T\,\mathrm{d}S-P\,\mathrm{d}V+\mu\,\mathrm{d}N$$

We want $\frac{\partial T}{\partial S}$.

We know $T=\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}$, so $\frac{\partial T}{\partial S}$ is the second derivative of the internal energy with respect to entropy.

Comment: Maybe you could be more explicit about the difference in slope in the liquid and superheated regime.